# georeferencing with gdal goes wrong

Tags: gdal

although there are several pages dedicated to this task, it seems that i can not make that work. I have a non georeferenced tif file which I provide you the output from gdalinfo

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Arctic_r05c02.2017235.terra.250m.tif
Size is 4096, 4096
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=ppm2geotiff v0.0.9
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 4096.0)
Upper Right ( 4096.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 4096.0, 4096.0)
Center      ( 2048.0, 2048.0)
Band 1 Block=4096x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=4096x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=4096x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

I do have the corner coordinate extention in lat/lon. Hence I am creating Ground Control Points with thee following command:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 0 0 -180.0000 +63.1066 -gcp 0 4096 -161.5651 +68.5979 -gcp 4096 0 +161.5651 +68.5979 -gcp 4096 4096 -180.0000 +76.3728 input.tif output.tif
```

which results to:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Arctic_r05c02.2017235.terra.250mproj.tif
Size is 4096, 4096
Coordinate System is `'
GCP Projection = 
GCP[  0]: Id=1, Info=
          (0,0) -> (-180,63.1066,0)
GCP[  1]: Id=2, Info=
          (0,4096) -> (-161.5651,68.5979,0)
GCP[  2]: Id=3, Info=
          (4096,0) -> (161.5651,68.5979,0)
GCP[  3]: Id=4, Info=
          (4096,4096) -> (-180,76.3728,0)
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=ppm2geotiff v0.0.9
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 4096.0)
Upper Right ( 4096.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 4096.0, 4096.0)
Center      ( 2048.0, 2048.0)
Band 1 Block=4096x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=4096x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=4096x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

The next step is to resample with gdalwarp in order to create a projected file.

```
gdalwarp -r near -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3413 -tr 250 250 input.tif output.tif
```

But the file seems distort:
[image]

Any idea what I can further do? Is there a way to directly change the corner coordinates inside the tiff file instead of adding GCP's? Would that help?

Some more information which i forgot. The data can be downloaded at:

```
https://lance-modis.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?subset=Arctic_r05c02.2017235.terra.250m
```

and for the bounding box definition:

```
https://lance-modis.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?subset=Arctic_r05c02.2017235.terra.250m.met
```

Since the box definition from NASA's side looks a bit odd, i tried the same procedure for the following tile:

```
https://lance-modis.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?subset=Arctic_r04c03.2017235.terra.250m
```

and box definition:

```
https://lance-modis.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?subset=Arctic_r04c03.2017235.terra.250m.met
```

Although the box looks ok the following image was produced:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you mapped the coordinates correctly? For example, your upper left x coordinate (longitude) is the same as your lower right x coordinate, both -180. Its not impossible, but it implies your input data is rotated like 45 degrees with respect to epsg:4326. Any chance the input data is public? Its guessing otherwise.

Comment: Hi Rutger and thank you for your post. You are right about the box definition. That is why I tried that with another tile. I updated my post to include data sources and what I have done so far. Hope that helps a bit to find what is wrong here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you downloaded is already projected (in epsg:3413), you are assigning a projection (epsg:4326) and bounding-box which is not correct.

You can view the correct settings by visiting:
https://lance-modis.eosdis.nasa.gov/imagery/subsets/?subset=Arctic_r05c02.2017235.terra.250m.gdal

About halfway down on the page you'll see the `gdal_translate` command, use that with your in- and outputs.

For example:
`gdal_translate -of GTiff -outsize 4096 4096 -projwin -2097152 2097152 -1048576 1048576 -a_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" Arctic_r05c02.2017235.terra.250m.tif Arctic_r05c02.2017235.terra.250m_output.tif`

Comment: Brilliant! That was the missing part i  have been looking of. The site you provided, contains the relevant information to download the correct area extension for each of the tiles. It seems that if you look the metadata from the lance server contains some errors on the bounding box. The data I download are directly from lance server and they are not projected. The xml description + gdal downloads data from gibs.earthdata and those files are georeferenced. Many thanks for the great help!

Comment: Great! I think the data is correctly 'projected', but the metadata is missing/lacking. You could look into `gdal_edit.py` to only change the metadata (inplace). This could offer some performance gains compared to `gdal_translate` which copies the data.
http://www.gdal.org/gdal_edit.html